# How to enable color globally for all Julia scripts?

Tags: julia

Would like to enable color in output of all `Julia` scripts.

Is there some global config or environment variable to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "enable color". What result are you expecting to see?

Comment: @DavidVarela I run script with `julia myscript.jl` and `styledprint` prints colored output.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `--color` command line option when starting Julia.

```sh
$ julia --color yes
```

If the current terminal supports colors than Julia will use it.
Other command line options for `--color` are `auto` and `no`.
By default Julia is using the color terminal.

Once the terminal is started you can use `printstyled` to have colored output.

```
julia> printstyled("Hello world in yellow", color=:yellow)
Hello world in yellow
```

Comment: Thanks, but this way you have to explicitly specify `--color` option every time you run julia, i was thinking maybe there's some environment variable that could be set globally.

Comment: I believe that all you can do is to create your own julia bash file that points to the julia executable with ` --color yes` parameter

Comment: See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/34317 and https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/34347 for default enabling of color whenever stdin/stdout is a TTY.